# File transfer to wear fails for apk

Tags: android, adb, wear-os

Normal file transfers work fine (1.56MB & 6.7MB), but apk (1.81MB) fails:

```
>adb -s localhost:4444 push IMG_20141219_210043.jpg /storage/sdcard0/Download
45 KB/s (1637405 bytes in 35.128s)

>adb -s localhost:4444 push javamagazine20120708-dl.pdf /storage/sdcard0/Download
40 KB/s (7035111 bytes in 171.628s)

>adb -s localhost:4444 push wear-debug.apk /storage/sdcard0/Download
protocol failure
```

Same happens when installing via Android Studio:

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: motorola-moto_360-localhost:4444
Uploading file
  local path: C:\workspace\Heating\wear\build\outputs\apk\wear-debug.apk
  remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.mypackage.heating
I/O Error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Been developing and testing on wear (Moto360) the whole afternoon (and a month before that) w/o a problem, and all of a sudden AS started failing with `I/O Error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`.

Tried restarting wear, phone, PC, adb, same result...

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real reason for both `adb push` and Studio install failures: **bad USB cable** :(

With different cable all works fine, even the APK push:

```
C:\workspace\Heating\wear\build\outputs\apk>adb -s localhost:4444 push wear-debug.apk /storage/sdcard0/Download
45 KB/s (1907880 bytes in 40.722s)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Some android devices dont let .apk file transfer** for example u cant send or receive .apk files on Nexus 5...I'm not sure about ur wear device but that may be the case...As a solution u can rename the apk files to sth else (i usually use .mp3) and try sending the file after that. ;) then in the ur wear device rename it to .apk :D

Comment: I tried with .ap, fails the same. And I wouldn't even tried manual push if install from Studio didn't stop working.

Comment: Found a real reason: bad USB cable :(

Comment: Well...dunno what to do with that really...I'm not a pro so i just tried suggesting a soloution and a problem i've had with a friend's Nexus 5 :D

Comment: I guess the .apk push is not restricted on Moto360. Thanks for the suggestion, though.